# Is it $NP$-complete to decompose bridgeless cubic bipartite graph into edge-disjoint paths of length 3?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Motivated by this post on [cubic graphs decompositions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156455/cubic-graphs-decompositions), I am interested in decomposing a connected bridgeless graph into edge-disjoint paths of length 3 (P4). My intuition is that it should be NP-complete but did not find a reduction.

I am aware that it is $NP$-complete to decide whether a cubic bipartite planar graph is decomposable into vertex-disjoint paths of length 2 (P3).

> Is it $NP$-complete to decide whether a bridgeless cubic bipartite graph is decomposable into edge-disjoint paths of length 3 (P4)?

In a related note, Barnette conjecture states that every 3-connected cubic bipartite planar graph is Hamiltonian. This is equivalent to decomposing every such graph into Hamiltonian cycle and a perfect matching. [Feder and Subi](http://theory.stanford.edu/~tomas/barnew.pdf) proved that if there is a single graph in the class of the conjecture which does not admit such decomposition then deciding the existence of Hamiltonian cycle in $NP$-complete in that class.

> For general connected cubic graph decomposition problems, under which conditions does the existence of a non-decomposable graph imply the $NP$-completeness of the decomposition problem?

**EDIT** For the second question, Is there a subclass of connected bridgeless cubic graphs where non-decomposable graphs exist but it is polynonial time to decide the existence of a (edge) decomposition?

The linked post on MthOverflow provides some interesting examples of connected cubic graph decomposition problems.

**EDIT** The problem is posted on MathOverflow: [Connection between Barnette conjecture and hardness of cubic graph decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200421/connection-between-barnette-conjecture-and-hardness-of-cubic-graph-decomposition)

Comment: Very interesting question...care to share the polynomial time reduction from an NP-complete problem to the bicubic planar graph decomposition problem (for vertex-disjoint paths of length 2)?

Comment: @Philip White Here is the reduction http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11752578_121#page-1

Comment: It's behind a paywall, can you just tell me what problem it's a reduction from?

Comment: @PhilipWhite They proved that perfect P3-matching in cubic bipartite planar 2-connected graphs is NP-complete. The reduction is from 3D matching for planar instances.

Comment: For edge decomposition what are the known results? Is it NPC to find an edge disjoint P4 decomposition on cubic bipartite graphs? (i.e. dropping the "bridgless" constraint)

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi I am not aware of such result. I know that edge-disjoint claw decomposition of graphs in your class is polynomial time since every such graph has claw decomposition.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: ok, I thought that if you asked for bridgeless then the problem was known for the more general class. Another trivial question: what is exactly a *vertex-disjoint* decomposition of a graph in P3 paths? (if you fix the size of the elements used to decompose the graph and ask for a *vertex-disjoint* decomposition then the problem should be polynomial time solvable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As pointed out by David Eppstein](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2818/775) when I asked a related question a while ago: you can do that in polynomial time.

The idea is to find a perfect matching $M$ (which exists and can be found in polynomial time since your graph is cubic and bridgeless), and then to use the edges of $M$ as middle edges of the $P_4$'s.

To complete the construction, remove the edges of $M$ and orient the remaining cycles arbitrarily. Then attach to each edge $\{u, v\}$ of $M$ the arcs going out from $u$ and $v$, and you are done.

Comment: From MathOverflow answer, all graphs in the class are decomposable into edge-disjoint paths of length 3 (P4). It would be very interesting to find a class where deciding the decomposition existence is not trivial and polynomial time solvable.

Comment: 1) Yes, because all you need is a perfect matching and those graphs are known to admit one. 2) It's actually a necessary and sufficient condition (see again David's original answer).